# Assign number on specific line to a variable

Tags: java, regex, string, variables, substring

How do you assign an **unknown** substring (a Hex number) from a specific line in a txt file to a variable?

I've written the code to identify the necessary line and I've been told to use Regular Expressions (regex).

I don't know how to do that. Can it be done without regex?

This is an extract from an example txt file. I'm looking to get (and then compare ***Value(2)*** and ***Value(3)***) but I need the Hex numbers first.

```
Default(2) = 0x00
Value(2) = 0xE0A64F36
Desc(2) = calculated from application
Address(2) = 0x60
Page(2) = Sensor
Name(3) = ROM CRC32
Type(3) = u32
Default(3) = 0x00
Value(3) = 0xE0A64F36
Desc(3) = fix CRC from ROM
```

Comment: There's no need to write [Java] when `Java` is tagged.

Comment: Why do you emphasise 'unknown'?

Comment: Because this code will be used to open a number of files with this layout. I would have to go through each file, check the number and place in the code.

Comment: And do you have a problem with the iteration? You ask about extracting the value and I think we gave you some answers for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split by `=` and parse the hexadecimal number.

```
String s = "Value(2) = 0xE0A64F36";
String hex = s.split("=")[1].trim();
long l = Long.parseLong(hex.substring(2), 16);
// l == 3768995638
```

Comment: Sorry. It took me a while to go through these answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the extraction like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Value\\([23]\\) = (0x([0-9A-F]{8}))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(Long.parseLong(m.group(2), 16));
}
```

Notice: if you want only to test if value(2) and value(3) are the same, you dont need to convert anything. You can only compare strings.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to use regular expressions, you have to parse the string by the HEX pattern by yourself, such as getting the value part of the line (string after "=") and checking whether this part is in HEX format (starting with 0x and following characters are in 0-F) or using Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix) to try to parse it (catch the exception)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the strings already extracted and they are stored in 2 variables,

```
String value2 = "Value(2) = 0xE0A64F36";
String value3 = "Value(3) = 0xE0A64F36";
```

You can use substring and indexOf to get the actual value:

```
value2 = value2.substring(value2.indexOf("0x"));
value3 = value3.substring(value3.indexOf("0x"));
if (value2.compareToIgnoreCase(value3) == 0) {
  // Do something here
}
```